# how to instantiate different size icons based on the button pressed java

Tags: java, swing, awt, scaling

How can I change the size of icons that are instantiated based on a button pressed in a method.

so for instance this is what the buttons are instantiated as

```
private ExitProgramAction exitProgramAction = new ExitProgramAction("Quit",
      Resources.getIcon("exit16"), "Quit HEAT", new Integer(KeyEvent.VK_Q),
      KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_Q, java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getMenuShortcutKeyMask(), false));
```

but I am trying to change the getIcon() via the below method (which i created button for) when clicked.

```
protected class ZoomButtonAction extends AbstractAction {
    public ZoomButtonAction(String text, String desc)
    {
        super(text);
        putValue(SHORT_DESCRIPTION, desc);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can resize icons with the code below anytime you want.

```
protected class ZoomButtonAction extends AbstractAction {
    public ZoomButtonAction(String text, String desc)
    {
        super(text);
        putValue(SHORT_DESCRIPTION, desc);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

        ImageIcon icon = (ImageIcon)getValue(Action.SMALL_ICON);
        Image newImage = icon.getImage().getScaledInstance(width, height, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
        putValue(Action.SMALL_ICON, new ImageIcon(newImage));
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry if this sounds trivial but how I incorporate it with my code? so Resources.imageIcon.getImage("exit26").getScaledInstance();

Comment: what is the type of object that return after call Resources.getIcon(). If it is ImageIcon check my updated answer.

Comment: it doesn't return anything it just sets the icon in the toolbar, when the program is run

Comment: sorry one more thing, i got all my icons in a file, but where in you code do i point towards a particular icon file?

Comment: sorry I couldn't understand. would you explain more?

Comment: So in my program I have a folder for all the icons I'm using called icons. In this are a few dozen .png files. In one of my .java files I have created a JToolbar with Jbuttons on it that do different things. Each Jbutton has one of these .png files allocated to it.

I want to introduce a new button that, when clicked, increases the size of all of the icons in the toolbar. I've placed your code in an actionPerformed method but I'm not sure how to get it to point towards the particular .png files that I want it to enlarge

Comment: You must set all icons one by one. 

ImageIcon icon = (ImageIcon)OneOfAction.getValue(Action.SMALL_ICON);
Image newImage = icon.getImage().getScaledInstance(width, height, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
OneOfAction.putValue(Action.SMALL_ICON, new ImageIcon(newImage));